# Target flash version with the compiler

Tags: flash, compilation, target, mxmlc

When I run mxmlc with the -target-player attribute, it reports, "unknown configuration variable 'target-player'".

How to specify the target player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the problem.

I was using the version 2 of the mxmlc compiler.  I needed to use version 3.